# Using Mathematica Gather/Collect properly

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How do I use Mathematica's Gather/Collect/Transpose functions to convert:

```
{ { {1, foo1}, {2, foo2}, {3, foo3} }, { {1, bar1}, {2, bar2}, {3, bar3} } }
```

to

```
{ {1, foo1, bar1}, {2, foo2, bar2}, {3, foo3, bar3} }
```

EDIT: Thanks! I was hoping there was a simple way, but I guess not!

Comment: IMHO the functional requirement could have been written somewhat better. Your example leaves much to be guessed.

Comment: Yes, please update the question to be more specific.  Currently it is quite ambiguous.

Comment: barrycarter, I am still waiting for a clarified question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is your list:

```
tst = {{{1, foo1}, {2, foo2}, {3, foo3}}, {{1, bar1}, {2, bar2}, {3,  bar3}}}
```

Here is one way:

```
In[84]:= 
Flatten/@Transpose[{#[[All,1,1]],#[[All,All,2]]}]&@
  GatherBy[Flatten[tst,1],First]

Out[84]= {{1,foo1,bar1},{2,foo2,bar2},{3,foo3,bar3}}
```

**EDIT**

Here is a completely different version, just for fun:

```
In[106]:= 
With[{flat = Flatten[tst,1]},
   With[{rules = Dispatch[Rule@@@flat]},
       Map[{#}~Join~ReplaceList[#,rules]&,DeleteDuplicates[flat[[All,1]]]]]]

Out[106]= {{1,foo1,bar1},{2,foo2,bar2},{3,foo3,bar3}}
```

**EDIT 2**

And here is yet another way, using linked lists and inner function to accumulate the results:

```
In[113]:= 
Module[{f},f[x_]:={x};
  Apply[(f[#1] = {f[#1],#2})&,tst,{2}];
  Flatten/@Most[DownValues[f]][[All,2]]]

Out[113]= {{1,foo1,bar1},{2,foo2,bar2},{3,foo3,bar3}}
```

**EDIT 3**

Ok, for those who consider all of the above too complicated, here is a really simple rule - based solution:

```
In[149]:= 
GatherBy[Flatten[tst, 1], First] /. els : {{n_, _} ..} :> {n}~Join~els[[All, 2]]

Out[149]= {{1, foo1, bar1}, {2, foo2, bar2}, {3, foo3, bar3}}
```

Comment: In Edit 3, what does `els :` mean, or do? Is it a way to name the pattern that follows?

Comment: @David: The standard `x_` is actually short for `x:_`, but the former is so common that many people don't recognize the latter. Both are read "the pattern named `x` that matches `Blank[]`".

Comment: @Simon Your explanation makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps easier:

```
tst = {{{1, foo1}, {2, foo2}, {3, foo3}}, {{1, bar1}, {2, bar2}, {3,  bar3}}};

GatherBy[Flatten[tst, 1], First] /. {{k_, n_}, {k_, m_}} -> {k, n, m}
(*
-> {{1, foo1, bar1}, {2, foo2, bar2}, {3, foo3, bar3}}
*)
```

Comment: I did not see you solution until my last edit. I was thinking along the same lines, but the main problem that took me some time to figure out was to handle arbitrary number of terms in the sublists in the rule-based approach - yours only handles exactly two terms.

Comment: @Leonid You are right, but I am not sure if such generalization is asked for in the question

Answer (score 5):

**MapThread**

If the "foo" and "bar" sublists are guaranteed to be aligned with one another (as they are in the example) and if you will consider using functions other than `Gather`/`Collect`/`Transpose`, then `MapThread` will suffice:

```
data={{{1,foo1},{2,foo2},{3,foo3}},{{1,bar1},{2,bar2},{3,bar3}}};

MapThread[{#1[[1]], #1[[2]], #2[[2]]}&, data]
```

result:

```
{{1, foo1, bar1}, {2, foo2, bar2}, {3, foo3, bar3}}
```

**Pattern Matching**

If the lists are *not* aligned, you could also use straight pattern matching and replacement (although I wouldn't recommend this approach for large lists):

```
data //.
  {{h1___, {x_, foo__}, t1___}, {h2___, {x_, bar_}, t2___}} :>
  {{h1, {x, foo, bar}, t1}, {h2, t2}} // First
```

**Sow/Reap**

A more efficient approach for unaligned lists uses `Sow` and `Reap`:

```
Reap[Cases[data, {x_, y_} :> Sow[y, x], {2}], _, Prepend[#2, #1] &][[2]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Also just for fun ...

```
DeleteDuplicates /@ Flatten /@ GatherBy[Flatten[list, 1], First]
```

where

```
list = {{{1, foo1}, {2, foo2}, {3, foo3}}, {{1, bar1}, {2, bar2}, {3, 
    bar3}}}
```

Edit.

Some more fun ...

```
Gather[#][[All, 1]] & /@ Flatten /@ GatherBy[#, First] & @ 
 Flatten[list, 1]
```

Comment: @Simon yes, that's the most direct way to do it. but where's the fun in that? :)

Comment: @Simon.  I didn't see your code.  I posted this just as WReach posted his answer. I thought about deleting it but decided to leave it there ...

Comment: @TomD: I didn't post my code - since you beat me to it. So I upvoted your answer instead - leave it or my vote is wasted!

Comment: @Simon Thanks! Upvotes are scarce of late (but I am learning a lot) :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I would do it using the version of SelectEquivalents I posted in [What is in your Mathematica tool bag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/6245166#6245166)

```
l = {{{1, foo1}, {2, foo2}, {3, foo3}}, {{1, bar1}, {2, bar2}, {3, bar3}}};

SelectEquivalents[
   l
   ,
   MapLevel->2
   ,
   TagElement->(#[[1]]&)
   ,
   TransformElement->(#[[2]]&)
   ,
   TransformResults->(Join[{#1},#2]&)
]
```

This method is quite generic. I used to use functions such as GatherBy before for treating huge lists I generate in Monte-Carlo simulations. Now with SelectEquivalents implementations for such operations are much more intuitive. Plus it is based on the combination Reap and Sow which is very fast in Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

Until the question is updated to be more clear and specific, I will assume what I want to, and suggest this:

```
UnsortedUnion @@@ #~Flatten~{2} &
```

See:  [`UnsortedUnion`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246330/delete-repeating-list-elements-preserving-order-of-appearance/5248866#5248866)

Comment: Welcome back mr.wizard. Had a good vacation? Did you see this question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/6505675/615464)? I think you'll like it ;-)

Comment: @Sjoerd Thanks, and yes.  No, I had not.  LOL!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit overcomplicated, but:

```
lst = {{{1, foo1}, {2, foo2}, {3, foo3}}, {{1, bar1}, {2, bar2}, {3, bar3}}}

Map[
    Flatten,
    {Scan[Sow[#[[1]]] &,
                Flatten[lst, 1]] // Reap // Last // Last // DeleteDuplicates,
    Scan[Sow[#[[2]], #[[1]]] &,
            Flatten[lst, 1]] // Reap // Last} // Transpose
]
(*
{{1, foo1, bar1}, {2, foo2, bar2}, {3, foo3, bar3}}
*)
```

Here's how this works:

```
Scan[Sow[#[[1]]] &,
    Flatten[lst, 1]] // Reap // Last // Last // DeleteDuplicates
```

returns the unique first elements of each of your list items, in the order they were sown (since `DeleteDuplicates` never reorders elements). Then,

```
Scan[Sow[#[[2]], #[[1]]] &,
        Flatten[lst, 1]] // Reap // Last
```

exploits the fact that `Reap` returns expressions sown with difference tags in different lists. So then put them together, and transpose.

This has the disadvantage that we scan twice.

EDIT:

This

```
Map[
    Flatten,
    {DeleteDuplicates@#[[1]],
            Rest[#]} &@Last@Reap[
                Scan[(Sow[#[[1]]]; Sow[#[[2]], #[[1]]];) &,
                    Flatten[lst, 1]]] // Transpose
]
```

is (very) slightly faster, but is even less readable...